# Can you produce a .twbx file from Tableau Public that users can use Tableau Reader to read?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Public to do a POC (proof of concept) for the first time. On the Tableau Public website I see how to download the .twbx file but is there a way for users to use TableauReader to read it?  I am getting a prompt to start a trial of Tableau Desktop.

Do I need to buy Tableau Desktop in order to distribute a .twbx file for users to read it with their Tableau Readers, or is there a way where I can create a dashboard with Tableau Public?

Comment: If the workbook is on Tableau Public, can't your intended audience just access it on the public website and not need to use Reader?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  For now, yes.  I will go see how easy that is to get a URL generated, that I now see is also possible.

Comment: Actually, you've answered my question.  I need to buy Tableau Desktop.

Comment: Let me ask the question, again.  If i buy Tableau Desktop, will I be able to distribute the .twbx files to users who use Tableau Reader.  I can't use the Tableau Public server to deliver content.

Comment: To your last question: Yes, if you have Tableau Desktop you are able to save your dashboard as a .twbx file (with all the data included). If you send/distribute this .twbx file to others, then they can open it with Tableau Reader. They are then able to filter, zoom, pan,  etc., but they can't edit the workbooksheets or add data to it (They would also need to have Tableau Desktop for that).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  That's just what I need to know!